# Enumerate out of box

Tags: lyx, enumerate, babel, hebrew, right-to-left

I'm trying to make an enumerated list inside a box, but the bullets/numbers appears out of the box margins.
Is there a way to fix that?

[image: enumerate out of box]

code:

```
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage[latin9,cp1255]{inputenc}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\noindent\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{1\columnwidth - 2\fboxsep - 2\fboxrule}%
�����:
\begin{enumerate}
\item ����������
\item ���������
\item �������
\end{enumerate}
%
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As always on this site please post a full minimal example. Then we know what you are doing and can give better advise. Images does not help much without code

Comment: Hi, thank you. I just did (insert > box > Simple frame) and then I chose "Numbered list"

Comment: Code code code. And you should probably also mention what editor you use as the rest of us does not insert a box via insert.

Comment: Honestly I don't know how to add code . I'm using lyx (a beginner, as you can tell...)

Comment: That information about LyX is very important to your question, please add that tag, because LyX users are rather limited in comparison to the rest of us. I'd suggest you make a copy of your file. Delete everything except the box. Save this new file under yet another name and make sure the file format is "portable latex". This generates a tex file not a LyX file. Oleawe update your question with the contents of this tex file. The problem for us is that there are many ways to do boxes and configure lists in latex. So without seeing your actual code we cannot advise.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've added the code now.

Comment: That is better. I'm not at a pc so cannot help more at the moment. I'm wondering whether the Hebrew setup (presumably via babel) actually sets enumerate items in the margin by default. In a normal Hebrew doc will the item number then also ne outside the text block? Because then there isn't much we can do other than redefine stuff.

Comment: Is there a chance you could change the input encoding of the tex file from a mixture of `latin9` and `cp1255` to `UTF8`?